# How to Integrate Multi participant more than 2 Video Meeting in Twilio Android sdk

Tags: java, android, video, twilio, twilio-api

This is Reference from https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android/tree/master/quickstart
private void addRemoteParticipant(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant) {
            /*
             * This app only displays video for one additional participant per Room
             */
            if (thumbnailVideoView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                Snackbar.make(connectActionFab,
                        "Multiple participants are not currently support in this UI",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                return;
            }
            remoteParticipantIdentity = remoteParticipant.getIdentity();

```
        /*
         * Add remote participant renderer
         */
        if (remoteParticipant.getRemoteVideoTracks().size() > 0) {
            RemoteVideoTrackPublication remoteVideoTrackPublication =
                    remoteParticipant.getRemoteVideoTracks().get(0);

            /*
             * Only render video tracks that are subscribed to
             */
            if (remoteVideoTrackPublication.isTrackSubscribed()) {
                addRemoteParticipantVideo(remoteVideoTrackPublication.getRemoteVideoTrack());
            }
        }

        /*
         * Start listening for participant events
         */
        remoteParticipant.setListener(remoteParticipantListener());
    }

    /*
     * Set primary view as renderer for participant video track
     */
    private void addRemoteParticipantVideo(VideoTrack videoTrack) {
        moveLocalVideoToThumbnailView();
        primaryVideoView.setMirror(false);
        videoTrack.addRenderer(primaryVideoView);
    }

    private void moveLocalVideoToThumbnailView() {
        if (thumbnailVideoView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            thumbnailVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            localVideoTrack.removeRenderer(primaryVideoView);
            localVideoTrack.addRenderer(thumbnailVideoView);
            localVideoView = thumbnailVideoView;
            thumbnailVideoView.setMirror(cameraCapturerCompat.getCameraSource() ==
                    CameraSource.FRONT_CAMERA);
        }
    }
```